# unable to get correct layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Following is the layout of app. It has two views under `viewflipper`. In the second view, there are 3 rows, row 1 has 3 buttons, row 2 has a image and row 3 has 3 buttons. I want row 1 to be aligned with the top of screen, row 3 to be aligned with the bottom of screen and the image to take the rest of space in between. Could anybody tell me how to achieve that ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!--adding views to ViewFlipper-->
      <!--view=1-->
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    >
    </TextView>

<VideoView
android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/b"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

       <!--view=2-->

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!--row 1-->
      <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Back" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Upload to Facebook" />
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button3"
    android:text="Save" />

   </RelativeLayout>

       <!--row 2-->
    <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>


  <!--row 3-->   
    <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Previous" />
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button4">
</Spinner>
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spinner"
    android:text="Next" />
 </RelativeLayout>



     </LinearLayout>

 </ViewFlipper>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` for the view.

Then on the first row use `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and on the third row use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Finally, on the image in the middle use `android:layout_below="@id/first_row" android:layout_above="@id/third_row"` with `fill_parent` for dimensions.